# How do i make a copy of an object? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a class in json format. I would like to make two instance. Right now (its pretty obvious why) when i 'make' two objects i really have 2 vars pointing to one. (b.blah = 'z' will make a.blah=='z')

How do i make a copy of an object?

```
var template = {
    blah: 0,
    init: function (storageObj) {
        blah = storageObj;
        return this; //problem here
    },
    func2: function (tagElement) {
    },
}

a = template.init($('form [name=data]').eq(0));
b = template.init($('form [name=data2]').eq(0));
```

Comment: Hope this posting helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: You may want to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object. It was answered by John Resig himself. There should be nothing more to add! :)

Comment: By the way, I think that `blah = storageObj;` should be `this.blah = storageObj;`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/122704#122704)

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple instances, sounds like a constructor might do you some good.

```
function Template(element) {
    this.blah = element;
}

Template.prototype.func2 = function(tagElement) {
    //...
};

var a = new Template($('form [name=data]').eq(0));
var b = new Template($('form [name=data2]').eq(0));

b.func2('form');
```

All methods on the function prototype (`Template.prototype`) will be accessible from each instance, and with each instance scoped accordingly. The new keyword will run the function and then return to you a brand new object, inheritting from the prototype.

You'll no longer have the exact same object point to `a` and `b`.

Answer (score -2):

```
var b = {}, key;

for (key in a){

    if(a.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        b[key] = a[key];
    }

}
```

Comment: Ouch, seems like I misunderstood the question...seanmonstar's answer is the way to go!

Comment: you did answer the title of the question. i just felt the constructor pattern fit better for his purposes